# Copy portion of text in a file and paste somewhere else on the same line within the file

Tags: windows-10, text-files

I have a text file (.cs file) with some information I want to copy from within the file to some place else on the same line within the file.

For instance, I have something like:

```
Random text here { Name = "Important - info", UniqueId = "1110100", More random text};
Random text here { Name = "More Important (info)", UniqueId = "1110101", More random text};
Random text here { Name = "Other Important info", UniqueId = "1110102", More random text};
.
.
.
Random text here { Name = "Other Important info 4/11", UniqueId = "2000110", More random text};
```

and I want the numbers after UniqueId to be copied and placed at the end of the name on the same line like so

```
Random text here { Name = "Important - info 1110100", UniqueId = "1110100", More random text};
Random text here { Name = "More Important (info) 1110101", UniqueId = "1110101", More random text};
Random text here { Name = "Other Important info 1110102", UniqueId = "1110102", More random text};
.
.
.
Random text here { Name = "Other Important info 4/11 2000110", UniqueId = "2000110", More random text};
```

As long as there is a space after the quoted name and then the UniqueId. The name can be anything, the UniqueId is unique for each name and each line. Is this task possible? I'll try any Windows program.

Comment: Your question as it stands, is not really about a programming problem. It looks like what you want to achieve, is a string that contains both the `Name` and the `UniqueId` of the object. I would strongly advise that you don't mix these two into the same property, but rather use a different approach, such as overriding the `ToString()` method of your object, to return the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking more for a way to do it in Notepad++ or Powershell or some kind of text-based way if possible, not as a programming problem. Should I try Stack Exchange?

Comment: You could maybe find a suitable answer, by asking on [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) (a site in the StackExchange network). They have a tag for questions related to Notepad++.

I still would like to know **_why_** you want to achieve this. You mentioned that it is a ".cs" file, so I assume it is a C# code file that initializes some objects in your program. It seems wrong to want to include the `UniqueId` in two different fields on the same object.

Comment: I have a bunch of other text files in various formats that I basically want to achieve the same thing with and then rename the extensions back to their original. This one just happens to be a .cs file which is why I didn't specifically tag it. Just wanted to find out if it was possible to copy part of a text on a line and paste it somewhere else on the same line and thought I'd ask the internet. I'm not even sure if it's achievable. At least you replied, so thanks again.

Comment: Hmm... I don't think I can be anymore specific. Using the first line of the example I posted, I want to copy 1110100 to the end of "Important - info" to read "Important - info 1110100", and so on. It doesn't have to be Notepad++, there could be another way out there that I'm not aware of. I'll try SuperUser.

Comment: Thank you @J.A.P , this is the answer I was looking for. I marked the answer up but my reputation is too low for it to count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you are asking by using any text editor that supports Regex. In this example, I will be using Notepad++. First I will describe what to do, then after I will explain what the Regex does.

**Example**

1. Open the file with `Notepad++`.
2. Press `Ctrl+F` to bring up the `Search and Replace` window.
3. Make sure to check the box named `Wrap around`
4. Select `Regular expression` under `Search Mode`
5. Under `Find What:` insert `Name = "(.*)", UniqueId = "(\d+)"`
6. Under `Replace with:` insert `Name = "$1 $2", UniqueId = "$2"`
7. Press `Replace all` once.

[image: Npp-with-regex]

**Understanding the regex**

- `()` these characters represent a group that you want to capture.
- `$1` represent the first group that you marked with `()`
- `$2` same thing but it takes the second group.
- `\d` matches `any digit`. `+` after a digit means, match one or more digits.
- `.` matches `any character`. `*` after the dot means match zero or more characters.

In the search example `Name = "(.*)", UniqueId = "(\d+)"` we have two groups. Matching the content in between the quotes of Name and UniqueId.

In the replace example `Name = "$1 $2", UniqueId = "$2"`, we are using these groups to replace what we match with something new. The new is, in this case, the contents of group `$1` and group `$2`.